# SSRS 2008 Report SQL options

Tags: sql, architecture, report, ssrs-2008

I would like some guidance on what is the best approach for storing the Report SQL definitions for SSRS 2008 reports.

[Our web app will interface with the SSRS web service and display the reports in the VS ReportViewer control]

Currently I see 3 options

1. Store the SQL within the RDL [Report Definition] files.
2. Store the SQL in Stored Procedure/View [1 SPROC per report/parent report]
3. Store the SQL for all the reports in a single Reports table that has a ReportNameORGUID and ReportSQL columns at minimum.

For the purpose of the question the report designers will [initially] be our own support staff that have a a 'working' knowledge of SQL. The aim of the development group however is to retain tight control over the database standards and schema.

**Option 1** allows for our own report designers to easily create and update reports but the SQL is distributed across all the reports and could be hard to control, maintain and update.

**Option 2** will have performance benefits but the number of SPROCS could increase to a large amount and there is a requirement for the report designers to have the ability to create SPROCS and there is then the question of SQL standards being enforced in the SPROCS

**Option 3** is attractive from a control point of view and we could provide a simple admin screen for designers to update the SQL to the Reports table but there is then the question of performance.

I would appreciate any input on addition merits or otherwise for the 3 options above and of course corrections to the assumptions I have made. If there are other options available it would be good to know.

The preferred solution from a DBA pov is detailed here
http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/ssrs-should-i-use-embedded-tsql-or-a-stored-procedure/

Thanks in advance,

Liam

Comment: That DBA seems like an idiot. "Oh noes! If we use embedded TSQL, the query optimizer may produce different query plans for different parameters!"

Answer (score 2):

I usually go with Approach #1. My SQL is embedded inside the report itself.

That keeps it consistent for me regardless of the Query Language - TSQL, MDX, PL/SQL, etc.